# how to fix php fatal error and http error 500 in wordpresss

Tags: php, wordpress

Can anyone tell me how to fix the PHP fatal error below?

> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/eazzyf17/public_html/wp-includes/post.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php54/usr/share/php') in /home/eazzyf17/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 166

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need more information to properly help you: what does your code look like (if any) and what have you tried so far? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: true, you have to provide more details. By the way, I've edited your post to improve formatting, wording and tags, now it's easier to note that it's about wordpress. To help you, we really need some more detail. Have you checked the presence of `wp-includes/post.php`? What does `wp-settings.php` looks like on line 166? Was it changed at some point and did it break it or you made a clean installation and got the error? May be it's worth asking at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com instead, but you have to answer the above questions anyway, so please edit your post

Answer (score 0):

try checking existence of file '/home/eazzyf17/public_html/wp-includes/post.php'.
if it exists then check for read permission which should be available for reading.

if it's on linux server then change mode to 767 which should do the magic.